# how to inherits method within same class? JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to inherit a method within same class. I have created a `connection()`, and i want to inherits it from `remotecmnd()` method. I have used `this.connection()` but still not getting it. In `connection()` i have declared socket variable and dataoutputstream variable. But `remotecmnd()` can not inherits it. so how can i do with it?

Here is my remotecmnd() :

```
public void remotecmnd(){
this.connection();
        shutdn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public String shutdn = "shutdown -s -t 10";
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        try{
                            out.writeBytes(shutdn);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Shutdown Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        restrt.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public String rest = "shutdown -r -t 10";
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try{
                            out.writeBytes(rest);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Restart Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        lgo.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public String logoff = "logoff";
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try{
                            out.writeBytes(logoff);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logoff Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

my connection method:

```
public void connection(){
try {
    Socket cs = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 8002);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
    if(cs.isConnected())
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (UnknownHostException er) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, er.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException er) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, er.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Both methods are in same class.

Comment: 'I want to inherit a method within same class' - I am sure that what you really want to do is something else. What are you trying to achieve? `out` is a local variable. I think you either want to make it a member of the class or return it from the `connection()` method.

Comment: First of all the thing you are asking is not called inheritance. This is simple method call which should work. Are you sure it's not being called. Try to debug the code and let us know.

Comment: @Pramod error is `error: cannot find symbol variable out`

Comment: @Axel sorry for that. I want to use variables from connection method in remotecmnd method :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need call that method from your `remoteCommand()` and Declare a variable `out` outside your method.

THis code will return `out`.

```
public DataOutputStream connection(){
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        Socket cs = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 8002);
        out = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
        if(cs.isConnected())
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (UnknownHostException er) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, er.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException er) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, er.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: thanks but its not working, still showing `cannot find symbol variable out`

Comment: Are you sure that the connection is established? Add a logs and check.

Comment: The variable ` out` can be accessed only within connection method. So declare outside of your method and inside the class

Comment: its not that solution i want. Could u tell me, how can i return the out variable?

Comment: Anytime :-) In stack overflow we won't accept thanks, Only up votes and accepted answers :-) Accept the answer if it is working. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not inheritance. You're asking about transfering the local variables of a called method to the scope of the calling method, which is not possible this way.

You could allow both methods to use the same variables by making it a field

```
private DataOutputStream out;

public void remotecmnd(){
    this.connection();
    // access DataOutputStream using this.out or out here
    ...
}

public void connection(){
    try {
        Socket cs = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 8002);
        out = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
        ...
```

However you need to be aware of the fact that if you catch an exception in the `connection` method, the field may still be `null` which may lead to a `NullPointerException`. You need some way of checking this in the `remotecmnd` method, e.g. by not catching the exceptions in `connection` or by rethrowing them.

---

Another option would be returning the `DataOutputStream` from the `connection` method:

```
public void remotecmnd(){
    final DataOutputStream out = this.connection();
    ...
}

public DataOutputStream connection() {
     ...
     return out;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override a method within the same Class.
 Overriding always requires inheritance relationship where a child type (class/interface ) inherits the method present in the parent type(class/interface ) and do modifications accordingly by maintaining the same signature.
    Example:

```
class A
{
public void method1()
{
...
...   //some definition

}

}


class B extends A
{
@Override
public void method1()   
{
.....
.....//same or different definition as in parent class A

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the out variable at class level and instantiate it inside connection. This will work. I think you already declared out variable at class level but creating another inside connection method.
Replace the line in connection method with this

```
out = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
```